# HIghcharts tooltip shows label from another serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have multiple series in a chart! This series are added according to user needs. 
The tooltip tool shows the label of a series even though my mouse is closer to another series.

here is an image showing the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKV6i.png

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        tooltip: {
            snap: 2,
            shared: true
        }
        yAxis: yAxis,
        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            enabled: true,
            series: {
                type: 'areaspline',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                dataGrouping: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                showInNavigator: true,
                stickyTracking: false
            },
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: dataFrame
    });
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your chart in an online code editor like jsfiddle? It's hard to see it on the image.

Comment: I will try to reproduce it on a Jsfiddle